# Routing for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have been searching for the way to configure default routing for  ASP.NET Core Razor Pages but still no success. This is my code for default routing. Anything else I can do? By the way, this is pure Razor pages without MVC.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext")));

            services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.RootDirectory = "/Bank";

            });
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know, that isn't covered by the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Does `AddRazorPagesOptions` cover your needs? Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#configuration-and-settings

Comment: i tried also but doesn't work. updated code in original post.

Comment: at the monent, i can only login using full path, http://localhost:53830/Bank/Login. I wish to just type http://localhost:53830 to route me to http://localhost:53830/Bank/Login

Comment: To specify that your Razor Pages are at a custom root directory in the app, you need to add `.WithRazorPagesRoot("/path/to/razor/pages");` after your `AddRazorPagesOptions`. And I think you can use `ConfigureApplicationCookie` to specify the LoginRedirection. Also you need to decorate your page with [Authorize]

Comment: Sorry, still can't get it. Any example?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the problem (from the comments section), you want to do the followings:

1. Add routing to custom razor pages.
2. Change Login page redirection.

---

You can do the following to add a custom routing to razor pages:

```
//This should be in the very end.
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
   //just to respect Microsoft way, it is better to have Pages folder
   //to contains your folders.
   options.RootDirectory = "/CustomFolder/Pages";
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

---

And to change the login page, you need to do:

1. Add [Authorize] to the pages you want authorization access. Or follow [Microsoft guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

If you have Microsoft scaffold-ed pages for Identity e.g.:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

you need to replace it with your own `Identity` (unless there is a way to override the defaults). Because the defaults would set the login path to: `/Identity/Account/Login`.

and after implementing your own Identity, you can set the cookies options.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
   options.LoginPath = "/Bank/Login";
});
```

---

Those steps worked for me. And if you insist of having the default Identity you can do add `CookieAuthenticationEvents` and then implement your own `OnRedirectToLogin`.

EDIT: Here is some useful sites:

1. [Razor pages configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#configuration-and-settings).
2. [Configure ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
3. [Customising-identity](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/identity/customising-identity).

Comment: thanks for this info. actually, at the moment, i am just using old school session. haven't implement asp.net core identity.

Comment: I tried your code. I think it does work half way. Now i am to figure out where to set my login page. services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                
                options.RootDirectory = "/Pages/Bank/";
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

Comment: AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

Page: /Index
Page: //Index

Comment: That's probably because you have a page inside `pages folder` that has the same name as a folder inside the `pages folder` with Index.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made changes here

```
 defaults: new { controller = "Bank", action = "Login" });
```

you should know what kind of action that you need to define in your controller. Normally keep either index or default and if your requirement is to redirect to login every-time app starts then you can set-up in your action.

For example to redirect login action

```
// 
// GET: /Account/Login 
 [AllowAnonymous] 
 public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) 
 { 
     ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl; 
    return View(); 
  }
```

Comment: If you want auto login, sure use Authorize attributes and setup authentication middleware?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core MVC itself uses the Routing middleware. You can use that directly if you don't want to use the MVC middleware.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRouting();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouter(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.MapRoute("default", "segmentA/{segmentB}");
    });
}
```